# Getting an instance of Play CacheAPI for use of Play libraries in non Play applications

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I want to use a Scala Play library in a non-Play application. Since the Play-library expect dependencies, which normally is provided via Guice, I have to provide them myself.

The class in the Play-library is specified like:

```
class X @Inject() (ws: WSClient, @NamedCache("cacheName") cache: CacheApi)
```

So first you have to add the Play dependencies in your build.sbt

```
"com.typesafe.play" % "play-ws_2.11" % "2.5.4",
"com.typesafe.play" % "play-cache_2.11" % "2.5.4",
```

Creating an instance of a WsClient is done via

```
val wsClient = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    AhcWSClient()
}
```

The default implementation of the Cache API uses EHCache.

I only haven't been able to find a way to instantiate one.
Does anybody have an idea of know how to provide the CacheAPI dependency?

Comment: You can look at the compile-time implementation to see how you can instantiate the component: [github](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.6/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cache.scala#L144). The cache seems to be tightly coupled with the `Environment` (lifecycle and resources)

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried and didn't find a way.

I ended up writing my own implementation of the CacheAPI trait